# How to Create a MySql Database using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Can we create a new MySQL database( not a table, I want a new database) from java code ? I have searched the internet and I get code only for connecting with existing mysql databases. Can i create a new database at run time using java code.

please help

Comment: Note that not all JDBC drivers supports all DDL statements and that it's generally considered bad practice to create db's and tables using JDBC, unless you'd like to (re)invent a DB manager tool in Java. For normal apps creating the datamodel ought to be a separate task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your connection string omit a database name and then execute Create database command.

Connection String: `jdbc:mysql://localhost`

Create Database Syntax : `stm.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE dbname")`

Answer (score -1):

```
Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver").newInstance();
String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDB?user=soft&password=soft1234&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=8859_1";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

Comment: Uhm, I think you didn't understood the question nor the already accepted answer :)